# Check if S3 downloading finish successfully

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I'm downloading a folder from S3 using Ruby and aws-sdk. How to check if each file is downloaded successfully? Is it simply a check if file exist on local machine?

```
   File.open("#{meeting_dir}/#{o.key}","wb") do |f|
      f.write(o.read)
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the file size of the amazon key with `S3Object#content_length` method and compare it with the size of the downloaded file `File.size 'downloaded_file'`.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#content_length-instance_method