# catch errors if s3 file is not downloaded

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I download a file from S3 like this:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.download_file('testunzipping','DataPump_10000838.zip','/tmp/DataPump_10000838.zip')
```

For now it always works. However, I wanted to add some sort of error handling. How can I check or get an error message if the download fails. How would I know that there's something wrong?

Does boto3 offer any error handling functions?

I read this: [Check if S3 downloading finish successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340835/check-if-s3-downloading-finish-successfully) but I am looking for alternatives as well.

Comment: See [How to handle errors with boto3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068055/how-to-handle-errors-with-boto3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have something like the below. Download and make sure it was created.

```
import boto3 
import os


def download_and_verify(Bucket, Key, Filename):
  try:
    os.remove(Filename)
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3.download_file(Bucket,Key,Filename)
    return os.path.exists(Filename)
  except Exception: # should narrow the scope of the exception
    return False
```

Comment: The download worked individually without this function but when I try to use the function, It gives the exception and later an error that ```[ERROR] FileNotFoundError:```

Answer (score 4):

This is just to improve the answer of @balderman, to actually check in exception what caused your BOTO request to fail.

```
def download_and_verify(Bucket, Key, Filename):
  try:
    os.remove(Filename)
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3.download_file(Bucket,Key,Filename)
    return os.path.exists(Filename)
  except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as error:
    print(error.response['Error']['Code']) #a summary of what went wrong
    print(error.response['Error']['Message']) #explanation of what went wrong
    return False
```

Comment: I get this error ```ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation:```. Which libraries do I need to import for this apart from boto3? I used ```import botocore
import os```

Comment: did you get this error as a response error message or as an exception in the code itself?

Comment: exception for the code itself I think. A normal try catch block works but not with the botocore exception

Comment: not always true in my case the boto exception system works just fine i am also using botocore to connect with s3